# "Basta" o "Basta con"

Tags: uso-de-palabras

El título ya lo dice todo. ¿"Basta leerlo" o "Basta con leerlo"? ¿O cualquiera de las dos formas es correcta?

En el caso de "alcanza" tengo la sensación de que cualquiera de las dos formas funciona, pero ¿quizás sin el "con" es más informal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creo que "basta con" es levemente preferible, pero las dos formas son correctas. Hay una pequeña diferencia de matiz.

Considera estas variantes; todas correctas y equivalentes:

```
   1. Para aprobar el examen, basta estudiar.
   2. Para aprobar el examen, estudiar basta.
   3. Para aprobar el examen, estudiar es bastante.  [=es suficiente]
   4. [El solo acto de] estudiar basta para aprobar el examen.
```

Las formas 3 y 4 suenan en este caso un poco forzadas, pero son equivalentes y sirven para destacar que, en todas ellas, sin el "con", "estudiar" (usado como sustantivo, como "el acto de estudiar") es el **sujeto** de la oración, y el verbo **bastar** es aquí **personal**.

En cambio, si digo

```
5. Para aprobar el examen, basta con estudiar.
```

estoy diciendo en esencia lo mismo, pero el verbo ahora tiene un matiz más **impersonal**, el sujeto desaparece, y "con estudiar" funciona como un complemento circunstancial. Esta forma es, creo yo, preferible.

Ver [diccionario de dudas](http://buscon.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=f8YD0URDlD6LRivIVz).

Answer (score 1):

`Basta leerlo` puede funcionar pero ese 'con' se le da más enfasís.  Sin el 'con'.. suele ser entendido como 'Deja de leer' o 'No mas leas'.. mientras `Basta con leerlo` significariía literalmente... "Sólo lo que tienes que hacer es leerlo".. , "Es mejor que lo leas"... etcetera...

Comment: En realidad,  "basta con " a veces se usa (mal) en reemplazo de "basta de", que corresponde al segundo sentido ("stop with that"), así que la confusión también puede darse con ese uso.